# How to visualize the learned trained weights in a keras model?

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, keras, jupyter-notebook

I would like to see the trainable weight values of my keras model with the goal seeing if large patches of zero's or 1's exist after training.

My keras is using tensorflow backend. This is running in a docker image and ran from a jupyter notebook.

Here is how far I have gotten.

print(model.summary()) will produce a list of all trainable parameters.

```
_____________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
input_1 (InputLayer)         (None, 512, 512, 3)       0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_1 (Conv2D)            (None, 512, 512, 16)      448       
_________________________________________________________________
activation_1 (Activation)    (None, 512, 512, 16)      0         
_________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization_1 (Batch (None, 512, 512, 16)      64        
_________________________________________________________________
max_pooling2d_1 (MaxPooling2 (None, 256, 256, 16)      0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_2 (Conv2D)            (None, 256, 256, 32)      4640
```

model.trainable_weights lets me see the underlying tensorflow variables.

```
[<tf.Variable 'conv2d_1/kernel:0' shape=(3, 3, 3, 16) dtype=float32_ref>,
 <tf.Variable 'conv2d_1/bias:0' shape=(16,) dtype=float32_ref>,
 <tf.Variable 'batch_normalization_1/gamma:0' shape=(16,) dtype=float32_ref>,
 <tf.Variable 'batch_normalization_1/beta:0' shape=(16,) dtype=float32_ref>,
 <tf.Variable 'conv2d_2/kernel:0' shape=(3, 3, 16, 32) dtype=float32_ref>,
 <tf.Variable 'conv2d_2/bias:0' shape=(32,) dtype=float32_ref>,
```

How can i print the values of these varibles to see how many get crazy value like 0, 1 or infinity?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The simplest way is to evaluate the weight tensors:

```
from keras import backend as K

for w in model.trainable_weights:
    print(K.eval(w))
```

`K.eval(w)` will return a numpy array, so you can perform the usual checks on that, e.g.:

```
np.isnan(w)
np.isinf(w)
w == 0
w == 1
```

and you can use `np.any` or `np.argwhere` to single out problematic values.

Cheers